# stream.readtimeout threw an exception of type 'system.invalidoperationexception'

Tags: c#, .net, opencv

I'm using OpenCV to detect a face and crop the face out of the image frame. The cropped image needs to be sent to Azure for facial recognition through the Face API.
The Face API library (`Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Face`) has an Detect function for a Stream and one for a URL. I've chosen for Stream because I don't want to upload the image first (performance).

The following part of my code runs when one (or more) face is detected. The detectedFaceImage is a Mat. I'm trying to convert this Mat to a Stream so that I can send it to Azure.

I don't get any errors at all, but as soon as I get to `byte[] imageByte`, the application stops working. After adding a breakpoint I've noticed that for the imageStream stream it shows:

> stream.readtimeout threw an exception of type
>   'system.invalidoperationexception'".

So I'm assuming it somehow can't read the Stream but I don't understand why. I checked the byte[] imageByte and it does have a value (not null) so that part seems to work.

```
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(faceRect.ToString());
                            var detectedFaceImage = new Mat(frame, faceRect);
                            byte[] imageByte = detectedFaceImage.ToBytes();
                            Stream imageStream = new MemoryStream(imageByte);
                            await GetFaceId(imageStream);
                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(e);
                            throw e;
                        }
                    }


                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    Console.WriteLine(faces);
                }
            }
        }
```

It doesn't do anything at the catch.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can see a more detailed exception message if u checked out CLR exceptions in your IDE. I understand it's obviously, but sth wrong with your incoming byte array :). Maybe   `imageStream.Position = 0;` can solve it, but I'm not sure. I need a more detailed exception message.